# Showing a diagram within a scrollable area

Tags: jointjs

Imagine I wish to have an area of my screen (eg. a box that is 500px by 500px) contain my diagram.  If my diagram has a width or height large than this, I would like scroll bars to appear to allow me scroll the diagram.  I tried to achieve this by placing my diagram within a sized `<div>` element but it seems that the diagram ignores this and it simply "spills out".  Has anyone tried to achieve this and may be able to share a recipe?

By using the Chrome developer tools, I see that I do indeed have a `<div>` that is 500px by 500px which appears to contain an `<svg>` that has a width of `1082` and the whole width of the `<svg>` is shown even though the `<svg>` is contained withing the `<div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a `<div>` is created to hold the diagram and it is given a width and height, set its `overflow` css property to `scroll`.  For example:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; overflow: scroll;" />
```

See also this Stack Exchange answer that was the core of this `jointjs` solution about adding scroll bars to an `<svg>`.

[How to get ScrollBars in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344688/how-to-get-scrollbars-in-svg)