# d3.js bubblechart : Make div scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, scroll

I have created a bubble chart using d3.js. I want to make the div in which bubble chart is displayed scrollable , so that if the no of bubbles exceeds the height of div ,scrolling is enabled.

I gave `overflow-y:scrollable` in css. But its not working. 
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salsa111/06xyo1tv/17/).

What am I missing ?

Comment: svg cannot have scroll bars, your best bet would be to put it in a parent div container with fixed height, and make the div scrollable. something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344688/how-to-get-scrollbars-in-svg

Comment: Your example: http://jsfiddle.net/06xyo1tv/20/ - so you'll have to calculate the svg size and adjust as needed

Comment: thanks @iamserious  it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by placing the svg inside a parent div.

```
<div class="parent">
<p id='chart'></p>
</div>
```

Then gave fixed height to the parent div and made it scrollable.

```
.parent {
height:400px;
width:400px;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Also made height of svg greater than its parent div.

```
svg{
background: lightgray;
height:600px;
width:600px;    
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salsa111/06xyo1tv/23/).