# Treelayout in Jointjs

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

I have a problem with the jointjs/rappid library. I'm using it for rendering the organization diagram and there are over 200 employees.
I successfully used the TreeLayout for rendering them out, however they are not stacking in the deeper branches, therefore the tree is huge and not readable. Is there a way to render it [similarly to their demo on the main page?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSdPa.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you saied

> deeper branches

i understand that the problem is to spread them on the paper.

If then, you can use scrollbars for your paper.

use this:
 [Scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344688/how-to-get-scrollbars-in-svg)