# Overflow in SVG

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, overflow, basex

i am using XSLT in order to show a list of games. Each game is positioned according to its position in the database (y="{($position)*10}%"). My problem is, that when too many games are in the database, these games are not shown. I also tried to use a  with overflow="scroll" but that didn't work. How can my output be also shown when the database grows, so that i can scroll and see all the games?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" overflow="scroll">
            <xsl:for-each select="//game">
                <xsl:variable name="gameid" select="@gameid"/>
                <xsl:variable name="name1" select="players/player[@id='1']/name"/>
                <xsl:variable name="name2" select="players/player[@id='2']/name"/>
                <xsl:variable name="points1" select="players/player[@id='1']/points"/>
                <xsl:variable name="points2" select="players/player[@id='2']/points"/>
                <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
                <text x="10%" y="{($position)*10}%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="100%">Id:</text>
                <text x="18%" y="{($position)*10}%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="100%" ><xsl:value-of select="$gameid"/></text>
                <text x="25%" y="{($position)*10}%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="100%"><xsl:value-of select="$name1"/>(<xsl:value-of select="$points1"/>) vs. <xsl:value-of select="$name2"/>(<xsl:value-of select="$points2"/>)</text>  
            </xsl:for-each>
        </svg> 
 </xsl:template>
```

Here is a part of the xml file. In the database this xml file is contained many times with different values.

```
<game gameid="2018-02-24T20:31:49.058>
 <players>
   <player id="1" playing="true">
     <name></name>
     <points>0</points>
   </player>
   <player id="2" playing="false">
     <name>awd</name>
     <points>0</points>
   </player>
 </players>
</game>
```

Comment: Posting a snippet of the XML to complete a [mcve] would help in finding the issue.

Comment: Okay thanks, i eddited it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set the vertical position *relative in percent* with the expression `y="{($position)*10}%"`. So when `$position` is greater than 10, the percent value surpasses the 100% mark and the item will not get displayed (e.g. 110% for the 11th item).

So a solution is to use *absolute values (e.g. in `px`)*:

```
{($position)*40}px
```

You will also have to set the `<svg height="...px"...` in the same way.

If you then wanted to use scrollbars to display a lot of items, [this SO question "How to get ScrollBars in SVG?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8344688/1305969) could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try it and tell you :)