# No scrollbar for SVG overflow="scroll"

Tags: svg, overflow

The [example in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow) renders without scroll bars in Chrome 86.0.4240.198 .

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" overflow="auto">
  <text y="20">This text is wider than the SVG, so there should be a scrollbar shown.</text>
</svg>
```

[image: No scroll bars on SVG overflow scroll]

I have changed the example to `overflow="scroll"` and it still does not work correctly (i.e. it does not show scroll bars).  Is there a work around?

Comment: No browser currently supports scrollbars on SVG currently I believe.

Comment: You can fit the text inside the svg element if you change the viewBox value according to the computed text length: `svg.setAttribute("viewBox",`0 0 ${text.getComputedTextLength()} 30`)`

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson .  Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta .  In this case it's text but in the example I'm working with I wanted to have some shapes and charts displayed correctly.

Comment: You can get the bounding box of the shape using `let bb = theShape.getBBox()`. Next you can set the `viewBox = "bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height"`

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not answer the question directly but works well as a work around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11449016/539490

Specifically put the SVG in a div, and let the div handle the overflow.

```css
    div {
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <svg></svg>
    </div>
```